# is there a docker image can start python app from git without Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker

like this:

```
docker run -e GIT_REPO=https://github/abc/foo -e RUN='python app.py' someone:3.6
```

then the image will:

```
git clone foo
cd foo
pip install -r requirements.txt
python app.py
```

We need to migrate many python projects to kubernetes cluster, for now, I have to 
 built customized docker image and push to private registry for each.

Comment: Have you considered cloning locally and using a volume mount to include the code?

Comment: yes, but it need installing requirement by pip

Comment: That can be done by chaining commands like in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, you can use any base-purpose OS like `ubuntu` with all stuff wrapped into `/bin/bash -c`.

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install ... && git clone ... && cd ... && python ..."
```

Comment: yes i know, but cmd is very complicated and slow in k8s. git repo is in our lan, so git is fast.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker image system is fundamental to Docker.  This is doubly true when using a clustered system like Kubernetes: if you build your application into images, your Kubernetes pod specifications can say `image: myregistry.example.com/app1:20190219` and this is native functionality, but if you want to try to do this without building custom images, it’s strictly worse than not using Kubernetes at all.

To give you some idea, it’s hypothetically possible to do this, but whenever you have an update, you need to *manually* push the updated application code to *every* node in your cluster, then restart every pod (probably with `kubectl delete pod`).  You wouldn’t be able to take advantage of core Kubernetes features like rolling updates of deployments or rollbacks of failed builds.  The tooling you’d need to do this is probably exactly the same you’d need to run the same application on the same hardware without Kubernetes.

I don’t really see much benefit to using Docker or Kubernetes to run code that only lives on the host system.  You can look at tools like Python virtual environments to get some level of package isolation between different components, and automation tools like Ansible, Salt Stack, or Chef to deploy non-Docker code in a clustered environment.